# Questions on Gensim create corpus from dictionary

Tags: python, gensim

I am new to Gensim and I am learning Gensim and followed the example here: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/gensim-tutorial/

I am not to sure about the last line that creates the corpus from dictionary. When creating the dictionary, we already used simple_preprocess to process the "documents" line by line. I was thinking while creating the corpus using the dictionary, we needed to use simple_preprocess again to process "documents" line by line. Is that redundant?

```
documents = ["This is the first line",
         "This is the second sentence",
         "This third document"]

# Create the Dictionary and Corpus
mydict = corpora.Dictionary([simple_preprocess(line) for line in documents])
# Why need to use simple_preprocess and pass the documents again while
# the last call already created the dictionary using simple_preporcess on documents
corpus = [mydict.doc2bow(simple_preprocess(line)) for line in documents]
```

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I understand now why it needs to pass the documents line by line again when creating the BoW. The Bow need to reference the original documents by the dictionary does not have this information.

Answer (score 2):

A `Dictionary` object maps each word in the corpus to a unique id whereas `doc2bow()` creates a bag-of-words (BoW) model based upon the supplied dictionary.

In my opinion, it's better to use `CountVectorizer` from Sci-kit learn for the BoW model because it comes with some useful parameters which are absent in Gensim's implementation, such as the `min_df` and `max_df` (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After some extra thoughts, I understand the reasons now.